# Mysql select multiple artist records per track using a junction table

Tags: mysql

First off, I'm not sure if it is possible to do this in 1 Query, I do hope so though.

I have these tables:

```
artist
- id
- name

track
- id
- title

track_artist
- track_id
- artist_id
(with UNIQUE index on the combined columns)
```

A track can have multiple artists, and an artist can have multiple tracks, thus both of them have a ManyToMany relation using a junction table.

Now I'd like the information about Track #1 including some form of array (as an value within that record, perhaps named `artists`) which contains all artist records that are related to that track.

Which in pseudo-code should end up looking something like this:

```
- id : 1
- title : "example Track Title"
- artists :
    [
     - id : 1
     - name : "Foo Artist Name"
    ],
    [
     - id : 2
     - name : "Bar Artist Name"
    ]
```

Is this possible? If not, what would be the best approach?

Comment: i think your searching for group_concat added an answer

Comment: I don't think sql can return a result like that format. Maybe you should do it use other program language.

Comment: @10086 I'm afraid so too, not that that's an issue, but I was hoping I could do this in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible you can do it using following query

```
    Select t.id,t.tital , group_concat(a.name) as artist name 
from track t join track_artist ta on t.id=ta.track_id inner join
 artist a on a.id=ta.artist_id group by t.id
```

Comment: please modify it according to your requirement

Comment: this will give track_id , title and "," separated list of artist

Comment: That's unfortunately not really what I'm looking for, I need to be able to keep the name related to the ID of the artist